# how to check for conditions

Tags: python, conditional-statements

This might not be a programming logic question, but what could be the best to use type. I have following two way, which can be the best way to use. If there is other way, I will be more than happy to know.

**Conditions/Values**

```
permission = True
user = {"id": 1, "username": "it.dumb", "password": "", "locked": True}
```

**First part**

```
if not permission:
    return "Error, you are not permitted"

if not user:
    return "Error, user not found"

if not user["locked"]:
    return "Error, user is not locked"

user["locked"] = False
return user
```

**Second part**

```
if permission:
    if user:
        if user["locked"]:
            user["locked"] = False
            return user
        else:
            return "Error, user is not locked"
    else:
        return "Error, user not found"
else:
    return "Error, you are not permitted"
```

Assuming these two codes are inside a method ;)

Comment: *"Flat is better than nested"* (`import this`). Also, you should `raise` errors, not `return` an error message.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A very pythonic answer - flat is better than nested, and better ask for forgiveness than ask for permission.

```
class AuthenticationError(Exception):
    pass

 ....

if not permission:
    raise AuthenticationError("Error, you are not permitted")

if not user:
    raise AuthenticationError("Error, user not found")

if not user["locked"]:
    raise AuthenticationError("Error, user is not locked")

user["locked"] = False
return user
```